# Troubleshooting the XLSX Package: Row Must be Integer Vector

Tags: r, shiny

In my R Shiny program, I have a snippet of code as follows:

```
read.xlsx(wb,sheet=5,rows=5,cols=9)
```

When I run my program, the error it generates is as follows:

```
Error in read.xlsx.Workbook(wb, sheet = 5, rows = 5, cols = 9) 
  rows must be an integer vector else NULL or NA
```

**What I Understand:**
The workbook object "wb" has been defined. It is in no way causing the issue. I believe that declaring "rows" and "cols" is causing in issue. By using the help() function, I found that these are parameters in the function for read.xlsx. However, when I checked the online documentation, I found that the parameters called are supposed to be rowIndex and colIndex. I do not want to use parameters such as startRow because I only want a specific value.

**What I Don't Understand**
I don't understand what the problem is. The numbers should be vectors. In any case, when I use the as.vector command like so,

```
read.xlsx(wb,sheet=5,rows=as.vector(5),cols=as.vector(9))`
```

I get the same error. I honestly do not know where my problem is, and I hope one of you folks can help me with this syntactical issue.

Comment: 5 is a numeric vector, you don't have to use as.vector

Comment: The [commit to add `rowIndex` and `colIndex`](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/commit/ed7094b757e307f461198ec22c82d82b5d238738) (v2.4.0, on Jan 31, 2015) was followed less than an hour later by a commit to [rename them to `rows` and `cols`](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/commit/acf79bc8d5466b1d7db3b1e37c83898d478bcdd4). Other things to check: can you confirm you have 5 sheets in the workbook? Without further testing, that seems like the next logical place to troubleshoot. Perhaps try `read.xlsx(wb, sheet=1, ...)` to see that the `wb` handle is valid.

Comment: For clarity: `rows` and `cols` specify *which of the rows and columns* to retrieve, so in this case you are retrieving a single cell, `$I$5`. In fact, it's interpreting that cell's value as the column name for a 1-column, 0-row `data.frame`, likely not what you want. Perhaps you're looking for `startRow`? (There is no `startCol`.)

Comment: You may also wish to try `read_excel()` in the package "readxl".  I have found it to work with fewer hassles, although it does not allow for exact cell import.  I prefer to select data from within the resulting data frame anyway.